# Obter valor y id de un button en html y pasarlo a variable PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo una tabla que lleno con una consulta  a mi base de datos, pero como son varias columnas solo muestro algunas, agrego un boton para abrir una especie de formulario que muestre todo el registro completo, esto lo intento hacer guardando el id del registro en el id del boton para posteriormente hacer una nueva consulta con el id especificado.  Aqui es donde no logro hacer la consulta, por que no eh encontrado como enviar el id del boton   presionado a php.

La pregunta es como puedo hacer eso.?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta seria mi tabla.

```
<?php
while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['idintervenciones'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['carpeta'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['numeros'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['juez'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['resolucion'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['objetivos'] ?></td>
    <td><button value="<?php echo $mostrar['idintervenciones']?>" class="edit" onclick="openForm()">EDITAR</button> <button name="<?php echo $mostrar['idintervenciones']?>" value="<?php echo $mostrar['idintervenciones']?>" class="edit" onclick="openVer(this)" action="">VER</button></td>
</tr>
```

Asi lleno mi tabla.

Esto seria mi php y js para intentar tomar el id

```
<?php
  $id = "<script> document.writeln(idRow); </script>";
  $conexion2=mysqli_connect("192.168.0.13", "base", "password", "tabla");
  $sql2="SELECT *FROM intervenciones where idintervenciones = $id";
  $result2 = mysqli_query($conexion2, $sql2);
  $mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
?>

function openVer(comp) {
  document.getElementById("ver").style.display = "block";
  var idRow=$(comp).attr("id"); 
}
```

ESTE SERIA MI CODIGO COMPLERO:

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="funciones.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_table.css">
</head>
<body></body>
<h3 class="titulo"> Intervenciones </h3>

<form name="back" method="post" action="Home.html" class="regresarform">
    <input class="btn__submit" type="submit" value="Regresar">
</form>

<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <th><b>id</b> </th>
        <th><b>carpeta</b></th>
        <th><b>numeros intervenidos</b></th>
        <th><b>Nombre Juez</b></th>
        <th><b>Numero de Resolucion</b></th>
        <th><b>Objetivos</b></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $conexion=mysqli_connect("192.168.0.13", "FGE", "MARJ901201", "mps");
    $criterio = $_POST['buscarporinter'];
    $variable_B = $_POST['dateinterv'];
    
    if($criterio === "1"){
        $FLAG_B = "carpeta";
    }
    elseif ($criterio==="2"){
        $FLAG_B = "numeros";
    }elseif ($criterio === "3") {
        $FLAG_B = "juez";
    }elseif ($criterio ==="4") {
        $FLAG_B = "resolucion";
    }elseif ($criterio ==="5") {
        $FLAG_B = "fechainicio";
    }elseif ($criterio ==="6") {
        $FLAG_B = "fechatermino";
    }elseif ($criterio ==="7") {
        $FLAG_B = "duracion";
    }elseif ($criterio ==="8") {
        $FLAG_B = "informeinicial";
    }elseif ($criterio ==="9") {
        $FLAG_B = "informemes1";
    }elseif ($criterio ==="10") {
        $FLAG_B = "informemes2";
    }elseif ($criterio ==="11") {
        $FLAG_B = "informemes3";
    }elseif ($criterio ==="12") {
        $FLAG_B = "terminacion";
    }elseif ($criterio ==="13") {
        $FLAG_B = "conclusion_ant";
    }elseif ($criterio ==="14") {
        $FLAG_B = "objetivos";
    }

    
    $sql="SELECT *FROM intervenciones where $FLAG_B like '$variable_B%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
 
    $A = array();
    $count = 0;
    while($mostrar1=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push($A, $mostrar1['idintervenciones']);
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar1['idintervenciones'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar1['carpeta'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar1['numeros'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar1['juez'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar1['resolucion'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar1['objetivos'] ?></td>
        <td><form action=""><button value="<?php echo $mostrar1['idintervenciones']?>" class="edit" onclick="openForm()">EDITAR</button></form> 
            <button name="ver" id="ver<?php echo $mostrar1['idintervenciones']?>" value="<?php echo $mostrar1['idintervenciones']?>" class="edit" onclick="openVer(this)" action="">VER</button></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $count++;
    }
    
    ?>
</table>

<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <form class="form-container" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <h4>Agregar Avance</h4>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Agregar Avance" name="avances" required>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">GUARDAR</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">CANCELAR</button>
  </form>
</div>
    
<div class="contain" id="ver">
   <?php
        $id = $_REQUEST["ver"];
        print("id select".$id);
        $sql2="SELECT *FROM intervenciones where idintervenciones = $id";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);
        $mostrar=mysqli_fetch_row($result2);
   ?>
    
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="contacts">
      <h3>Usuario: ----</h3>

      <ul>
        <li>Inteligencia. UECS</li>
        <li>Registro de intervenciones</li>
      </ul>
      <p>
        <button onclick="closeVer()">CERRAR</button>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="form">
      <h3>Información de  Intervención</h3>
      <h6></h6>
      <form class="formulario" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <p>
          <label for="">Carpeta</label>
          <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $mostrar[1]?>">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="">Numeros Intervenidos</label>
          <input type="text"readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $mostrar[2]?>">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="">Juez</label>
          <input type="text"readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $mostrar[3]?>">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="">Numero de Resolucion</label>
          <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $mostrar[4]?>">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="">Fecha de inicio</label>
          <input type="text"readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $mostrar[5]?>">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="">Fecha de terminacion </label>
          <input type="text"readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $mostrar[6]?>">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="">Duracion de Intervencion</label>
          <input type="text"readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $mostrar[7]?>">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="">Informe Inicial</label>
          <input type="text"readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $mostrar[8]?>">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="">Informe mes 1</label>
          <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $mostrar[9]?>">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="">Informe mes 2</label>
          <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $mostrar[9]?>">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="">Informe mes 3</label>
          <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $mostrar[10]?>">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="">Terminacion</label>
          <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $mostrar[11]?>">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="">Conclusion Anticipada</label>
          <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $mostrar[12]?>">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="">Objetivos</label>
          <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $mostrar[13]?>">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="">Avances</label>
          <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="7" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $mostrar[14]?>"></textarea>
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

> **ESTE ES EL CODIGO JS:**
```

```js
function openVer(comp) {
    document.getElementById("ver").style.display = "block";
    var id = comp.value;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "table_int.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("ver="+id+""); 
}

function closeVer() {
  document.getElementById("ver").style.display = "none";
}
    
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}

function ver(e){
    document.getElementById("ver").style.display = "block";
    var id = e.value;
       $.ajax({
            url: 'table_int.php',
            data: { ver: id},
            type: 'POST',
            }).done(function(data) {
            });
}
```

ESTE ES EL FORMULARIO QUE QUIERO LLENAR CON LA SEGUNDA CONSULTA:
SI COLOCO UN ID DIRECTO SI LO HACE BIEN SOLO QUE QUIERO QUE EL ID CORRESPOND AL BOTON ACCIONADO.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitas usar Ajax.

Comment: si lo que tratas es mandar el id de un registro especifico a la funcion **openVer** pasaselo como un parametro al boton **ver** ejemplo:  `<button name="<?php echo $mostrar['idintervenciones']?>" value="<?php echo $mostrar['idintervenciones']?>" class="edit" onclick="openVer('<?php echo $mostrar['idintervenciones']?>')" action="">VER</button>`, hay en la function openVer en el parametro `comp` debe llegar el id del registro

Answer (score 0):

Estás seleccionando por id, cuando tus botones solo le agregas `value`, pero como estás agregándole la función al botón, con pasarle el argumento `this` y leer su `value` ya lo puedes obtener, además necesitas de `AJAX` para poder mandar ese valor a tu archivo `PHP` donde harás tu consulta, te dejo un ejemplo, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
function ver(e){
console.log(e.value);

let id = e.value;

$.ajax({
     url: 'tuArchivo.php',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: '',
     data: {ver: id},
})
.done(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
})


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="editar" id="edit">Editar</button>
<button value="ver" id="ver" onclick="ver(this)">Ver</button>
```

Comment: De la forma que me señalas si obtengo el id en js, pero cuando lo trato de tomar en el fragmento de PHP me sigue indicando que desconoce la variable que le estoy pasando al $_POST. creo que debe señalar que todo esto lo estoy intentando hacer en un solo archivo PHP.

Comment: Agregare el codigo completo de mi Archvio PHP